# Windows Store App - XAML - Border filling page rather then wrapping Grid

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to put a `<Border/>` around a `<Grid/>` in a page, however the border appears to be bordering the page rather than the grid.

This is only XAML in my page element.

```
<Border Background="Black">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" x:Name="LoginCredentials" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username:" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="UserName" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextChanged="UserChange" Margin="5"/>
        <Button x:Name="LoginButton" Content="Login" Click="LoginButton_Click" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" TabIndex="0"/>
        <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

As a test I created a resource to fill the background of the `<Grid/>` with a colour and also filled the background of the `<Border/>` with a different colour. The `<Grid/>` ends up as a box in the center of the screen as intended, but the border `<Border/>` fills the entire screen. Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to get the `<Border/>` to fit around the `<Grid/>` as I want?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
<Border Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    ....
</Border>
```

As soon as i posted the question, what i was missing became clear!